# Visual C# SQL CLR Database Project on Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I am unable to find `Visual C# SQL CLR Database Project` on Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview. Only thing which is related to SQL Server is `SQL Server Database Project`.

What is the way of developing and deploying CLR Project for SQL Server on VS 11 Dev. Preview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that:

VS Team has got rid of all of the other SQL Project types and only included `SQL Server Database Project`.

I played with it for a while and does anything you need. Also, integration with Visual Studio is so great.